# Full website on Android

Tags: android, webview

How would I display a website's full website rather than the mobile website using webview? Whenever I use webview while developing it opens the mobile version of the site. I'd like it to open the full version (not sure what it's called - full/desktop version). I searched through the android api and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 4):

The website that you are viewing probably recognises the Android Browser User Agent, and adapts the content of the website to render specifically for mobile phones. Try [setting the user agent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setUserAgentString%28java.lang.String%29) to a desktop browser user agent.

For clarity - here is a sample Android browser user agent (Nexus one phone, running Android 2.2):

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-us; Nexus One Build/FRF91) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
```

And here is a Google Chrome user agent (on a Mac):

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.63 Safari/535.7
```

Comment: so what would I put in the parameter instead of ua? btw the phone I'm testing on is HTC Inspire running Android 2.3.3

Comment: Try passing a desktop browser user agent string, such as the Chrome one I have in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of user agent strings [here](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php). Use a desktop browser user agent string while using a webview.